# Can I use AtlasMap with an older version of Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, atlasmap

Our pom.xml shows camel-parent is set at version 2.24.0, and AtlasMap says since Camel 3.7. We will not be updating our Camel version anytime soon, that is an entirely different conversation (government project with no budget for that).

I'm pretty new to Camel - can I just add AtlasMap to the pom.xml and use it anyway? If yes, any advice like special steps, etc?

Comment: Unfortunately if the message schema's change the AtlasMap GUI expects you to start your mapping from scratch - you can't re-import a format. Ouch. Won't be using AtlasMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use AtlasMap with Camel 2.x: see https://docs.atlasmap.io/#running-with-apache-camel-2-x

Main differences are:

- use `atlas` instead of `atlasmap` as component schemein Camel URIs
- use io.atlasmap:camel-atlasmap as dependencies

Note that it was not a component provided by the Apache Camel projects in 2.x.